# Can I find out on the client which submit button was pressed when listening to the submit event?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, addeventlistener

Say I have a form with multiple submit buttons like so:

```
<form method="post" action="...">
   <input type="submit" value="search" name="a" />
   <input type="submit" value="search" name="b" />
   <input type="submit" value="search" name="c" />
</form>
```

I know I can listen to "click" and retrieve the respective element, but I would like to know if this was also possible when listening to `submit` like so:

```
 var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];

 function foo(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
   console.log(evt);
 }
 form.addEventListener("submit", foo, false);
```

**Question**:
Is it possible to retrieve the clicked submit button `name' when listening to the submit event?

Thanks!

Comment: console.log(evt.explicitOriginalTarget.name);? http://jsfiddle.net/8kkyrr6n/

Comment: Chrome says, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```
var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
 function foo(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
   var target = evt.explicitOriginalTarget.name || evt.relatedTarget.name;
   console.log(target);
 }
 form.addEventListener("submit", foo, false);
```

Comment: sorry, but on Chrome both `explicitOriginalTarget` and `relatedTarget` are undefined

Comment: @frequent try this `var target = evt.explicitOriginalTarget.name || evt.relatedTarget.name || evt.target.name;` Not tested, since i don't have chrome installed.